# Property 'LoginForm' does not exist on type 'LoginComponent'. Did you mean 'login

Tags: angular

I am not getting actually what the problem with this I have imported all the necessary and my angular project is running fine, but when I did ng build --prod it got me this error

Comment: Can you show your code please?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are importing the files correctly into your modules